# Where can I find a list of icons to be used in vuetify?

Tags: button, icons, vuetify.js

You can add an icon like `<v-icon>backup</v-icon>` but I can't find the list of supported words to be used inside the `v-icon` tag. There are lists for [Material Design Icons](https://materialdesignicons.com/) and [Font Awesome Icons](http://fontawesome.io/icons/), but what about the default ones?

Comment: https://pictogrammers.github.io/@mdi/font/3.6.95/

Answer (score 33):

Ok. I found in the [Vuetify Icons Documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/icons) that [Material Icons from Google](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline) will be used by default.

> Keep in mind that **Material Icons** are different from **Material
> Design Icons**!!!

I didn't notice that at first. That was my confusion.

https://materialdesignicons.com/

Comment: Vuetify uses many of the Material Icons but not all.  For example, table_chart does not function properly in Vuetify.

Comment: Vuetify uses [Material Design Icons](https://materialdesignicons.com/) as default not Material Icons.

Comment: Thank you...Super helpful your comment, I didn't know there was a difference between Material Icons and Material Design Icons, until I read your comment, I thought it was the same thing, with different names.

Comment: This is the css it imports by default, you can see a list of all icons: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.css

As others have noted it includes some of the Material Icons but not all of them.

Answer (score 5):

I thinks the answer for **Vuetify** list icons is this site below:
https://materialdesignicons.com/

Note: first icon is "ab-testing" so use it like this:
`{mdi-ab-testing}` and so on :)

> mdi(materialDesignIcons)+icon-name

good luck with that...

Answer (score 4):

try to do : `<v-icon>mdi-home</v-icon>`

Answer (score 1):

Change the name inside and you will get the different icon:

```
<v-icon>home</v-icon>
<v-icon>close</v-icon>
```

Find the right name for your app from:
https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline

Answer (score 0):

```
// Use this code.
    <v-btn color="error" fab small dark
      @click="yoursFunc()">
      <v-icon>list</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
```

From this official [doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/icons). vuetifyjs uses [material icons](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline).

> The v-icon component provides a large set of glyphs to provide context to various aspects of your application. Vuetify icons utilize Google's Material Icons font library. For a list of all available icons, visit the official Material Icons page.