# vuetify icon not showing

Tags: vue.js, icons, vuetify.js

I am using `vue.js` and `vuetify`. I want to add an icon but it is not working as expected (not rendered).

How can I fix this?

Please refer to the following code:

main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";
    
Vue.use(Vuetify);
```

index.html

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
```

calendar.vue

```html
<i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
```

I want it to look like an icon, not code.

> [image]

Comment: You've accepted the wrong answer. Are you able to change your selection to better help others in finding the right result?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57535771/5735265 should be the accepted result.

Comment: I changed my selection, thank you all for answering my question! :)

Comment: You'll need to install the wished icon pack, import the pack itself and its css and give your vuetify config a reference to it. In this article https://www.the-koi.com/projects/how-to-set-up-a-project-with-nuxt3-and-vuetify3-with-a-quick-overview/ under the section Resolve Vuetify Icons not shown you can see a complete example on how to do it.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

With Vue CLI 3 we have no **index.html** in the **src** folder so alternatively you can

```
npm install --save material-design-icons-iconfont
```

and import it in the **main.js** file

```
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'
```

Comment: this solution works for me. Another solution using fontawesome, follow the steps from official docs [here](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/icons#install-font-awesome-5-icons)

Comment: it works thanks, also with this alternative, we don't need to append a `mdi-` as a prefix

Comment: Be sure to use e.g. `mdi-airplane` and not `airplane` for material-design icons as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63411099/3469861) and [the docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/icons/) in the very first paragraph.

Answer (score 89):

Had this issue with Vuetify 2.1.3 installed via the vuetify-loader 1.2.2

Seems like previous solutions do not work becues the default icons library has changed to mdi-font.

Solution was:

```
yarn add @mdi/font
```

And in the file `main.js` (or `plugins/vueitfy.js` if exists) add this line below the imports

```
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
```

Comment: This is also stated in the official documentation - however issue is still there. The only way I get those icons to work is with the solution @hasnat Safder provided.

Comment: @Orochi they is defiantly something weird going on, I wish they will fix it

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me, not from Hasnat Safder. Except, I imported in main.js cuz I can't find vuetify.js

Comment: For me icons was shown in development (npm run serve) mode but NOT in production (npm run build). Installing fonts with 'npm install --save @mdi/font" and importing into vuetify.js saved my day.

Comment: Works with Vuetify 3.0.4 via npm @mdi/font and import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'

Comment: This was the solution for me using Vite/vue3

Comment: This was the only thing working for me.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me as well

Answer (score 42):

Worked for me:

```
npm install @mdi/font
```

and then putting this inside plugins/vuetify.js:

```
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
```

Using     "vuetify": "^2.3.19",     "vue": "^2.6.12",

Comment: Also worked for vuetify 3.0.1

Comment: Also worked for vuetify 3.0.4

Answer (score 7):

You can face the exact same issue if you use Nuxt.js. To solve this issue, you have to declare the Material Design  icons in your CSS ... through the CDN, for example, as below:

```
link: [
  { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
    {
      rel: 'stylesheet',
      href:
          'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Nuxt with Vuetify and Material Icons don't show up in Firefox:

```
npm install import @mdi/font
```

Then in your `nuxt.config.js` add the following entry to your `css` field:

```
css: ["@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css"]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
npm install @mdi/font
```

write in main.js(or plugins/vuetify.js)

```
import "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css";
```

I got this answer from here too and it work succesfully )))

Comment: Repetitive. Answer already present.

Answer (score 3):

Also check your **vuetify** **config** file `plugins/vuetify.js`

Additional mast be setting `iconfont: 'mdi'` . In same cases default is `iconfont:'fas'`

I spent many hours to find it)

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

const opts = {
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        //
      },
    },
  },
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi',
  },
};

export default new Vuetify(opts);
```

Answer (score 3):

> **This is how it worked for me**

**install**

```
yarn add @mdi/font -D
```

// OR

```
npm install @mdi/font -D
```

**Then add these to main.js or vuetify.js**

```
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

export default createVuetify({
  icons: {
    defaultSet: 'mdi', // This is already the default value - only for display purposes
  },
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the latest released docs and include below code in your index.html

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

[Reference](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ yarn add @mdi/font -D
```

// OR
$ npm install @mdi/font -D

```
// src/plugins/vuetify.js



import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi', // default - only for display purposes
  },
})
```

Comment: Why as a dev dependency though?

Answer (score 2):

For the users of Vuetify 3:

Install:

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free -D

npm install @mdi/font
```

main.ts:

```
enter code here


import "vuetify/styles";
import { createVuetify, type ThemeDefinition } from "vuetify";
import * as components from "vuetify/components";
import * as directives from "vuetify/directives";

import { fa } from "vuetify/iconsets/fa";
import { aliases, mdi } from "vuetify/lib/iconsets/mdi";
// make sure to also import the coresponding css
import "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css"; // Ensure you are using css-loader
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"; // Ensure your project is capable of handling css files

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  theme: {
    defaultTheme: "dark",
  },
  icons: {
    defaultSet: "mdi",
    aliases,
    sets: {
      mdi,
      fa,
    },
  },
  components,
  directives,
});

app.use(vuetify);
```

Credit: https://www.the-koi.com/projects/setting-up-vue-3-with-vuetify-icons-and-themes/

Comment: I had to change `import { aliases, mdi } from "vuetify/lib/iconsets/mdi";` to `import { aliases, mdi } from "vuetify/lib/iconsets/mdi.mjs";` for `TypeScript`

Comment: I'm using `import { aliases, mdi } from 'vuetify/iconsets/mdi';` for TypeScript by following this [Vuetify guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/).

Answer (score 1):

You can import all necessary styles

`app.scss`

```
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900";
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css";
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons";
@import '~vuetify/dist/vuetify.css';
```

Answer (score 1):

A [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57535771/3632441) from @Hasnat Safder works for me, but an order in main.js is important:

```
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css';
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
```

Answer (score 0):

The yarn way (similar to Hasnat's response):

```
yarn add material-design-icons-iconfont
```

and import in the vuetify.js file (or main.js if it doesn't exist) like so:

```
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: before my code]

it's wrok for me :) just install this package

```
npm install --save material-design-icons-iconfont
```

and import it in the main.js or vuetify.js file

```
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'
```

Answer (score 0):

After straggling with this, solved the issue by following vutify guide:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import { aliases, mdi } from 'vuetify/iconsets/mdi'

export default createVuetify({
  icons: {
    defaultSet: 'mdi',
    aliases,
    sets: {
      mdi,
    }
  },
})
```

and

```
$ yarn add @mdi/font -D
// OR
$ npm install @mdi/font -D
```