# Vuetify icons not showing correctly: they appear as as "$vuetify.icons..."

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, material-design-icons

I'm facing an issue with the icons in Vuetify not showing properly, for example below is the [Vuetify expansion panel](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels). I already tried the solutions in this question [vuetify icon not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57053728/vuetify-icon-not-showing), but they didn't work for me. You can see below that the chevron-down icon is showing as `$vuetify.icons.expand`. I've tried both importing @mdi/font which doesn't do anything for me... here's the code I'm using:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
// import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
    icons: {
        iconfont: 'mdi'
    }
});

//expansion panels
```

[image]

Importing `material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css`,  changes the icons into some weird icons.

[image]

Please let me know what could be the problem and what else I can try!

Comment: Could you include the versions for the relevant libraries? Also, just to be clear, there are two different icon libraries with very similar names. Make sure you're clear on the difference between `iconfont: 'mdi'` and `iconfont: 'md'` and which one you want to use. In your second picture you seem to be using confusing the two libraries. It's not clear yet why the first one isn't working...

Comment: On closer inspection... your code is a mixture of Vuetify 1.5 and 2. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using Vuetify 2...

I think the key thing you're missing is passing Vuetify to the Vue constructor, as described here:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#bootstrapping-the-vuetify-object

Like this:

```js
new Vue({
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  // ... all the other stuff you're currently passing
```

If you want to configure the font then you need to pass it to the `Vuetify` constructor, not `Vue.use`. e.g.

```js
const vuetify = new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi'
  }
})

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  // ... all the other stuff you're currently passing
```

`mdi` is the default icon set anyway, so you don't need to do this if you want to use that font.

The way you're importing the CSS appears to be correct. You should be seeing errors if you haven't done that right.

The current documentation is here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons. At the time of writing that's for version 2.1.0. Be very careful not to confuse the configuration required for Vuetify 2 with 1.5, they are significantly different despite some similarities. You also need to be clear that there are two fonts with very similar names, one configured using `iconfont: 'mdi'` and one with `iconfont: 'md'`. Both use the words 'Material', 'Design' and 'Icons' in their names depending on the context.

**EDIT by OP**

I can't put this in a comment, so I figured I'd edit the answer. This is what ended up working for me:

```js
// src/plugins/vuetify.ts

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify);

const vuetify = new Vuetify({
    icons: {
        iconfont: 'mdi'
    }
});

export default vuetify
```

Then in my other file where I use Vue:

```js
// other_file.ts

import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

new Vue({
    vuetify,
    // ...other stuff...
})
```

Comment: @NicScozzaro The plugin in your edit had two calls to `new Vuetify`. I've removed one of them.

Comment: Earlier when this worked for me I went "YES YES YES!" out loud, so thank you for helping give me that moment.