# Icons not displaying in Vuetify application

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have created a Vue.js application with Vuetify, however when I use the v-icon component the alternative text is displayed as opposed to the icon.

I have created my application following the quick start guide on the Vuetify website.

```
$  vue -V
@vue/cli 4.1.2

vue create my-app
cd my-app
$ vue add vuetify
```

I then simply add home to src/components/HelloWorld.vue.

```
<template>
  <v-container>

    <v-icon>home</v-icon>

  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',

  data: () => ({
  }),
};
</script>
```

When I run the application the word Home is displayed as opposed to the icon

Comment: Can you show an example of the markup you're using to add the icon?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vuetify icon not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57053728/vuetify-icon-not-showing)

Comment: @Tanner I have added the code from src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: @MatheusValenza afraid not

Comment: Try `<v-icon>mdi-home</v-icon>` instead of just `<v-icon>home</v-icon>` Docs: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/icons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the instructions here to install and use Material icons: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons#install-material-icons

Alternatively, you could use the default Material Design icons (yes, they're both different) and change your code to:

```
<v-icon>mdi-home</v-icon>
```

to use the icon from the default Material Design icons set.