# icons are not rendering in Vue2 + Vuetify 2 app

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, material-design

In my `Vue2` + `Vuetify2` the icons are not rendering in the display however the elements(icon) are present in the DOM

`package.json`

```
{
 "name": "sample",
 "version": "0.1.0",
"dependencies": {
  "core-js": "^3.8.3",
  "vue": "^2.6.14",
  "vuetify": "^2.6.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
 "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
 "@mdi/font": "^7.1.96",
 "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
 "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
 "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
 "eslint": "^7.32.0",
 "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
 "sass": "~1.32.0",
 "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
 "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.5.8",
 "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
 "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
},
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
 vuetify,
 icons: {
 iconfont: 'mdi', // default - only for display purposes
},
 render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
<title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <noscript>
  <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
</noscript>
<div id="app"></div>
<!-- built files will be auto injected -->
```

And the app component which is making use `vuetify-icons`

```
<template>
<v-row justify="space-around" style="margin: 25px;  border:5px solid #f00; height: 
100px;">
 <v-icon
  size="large"
  color="green-darken-2"
  icon="mdi-domain"
></v-icon>

<v-icon
  size="large"
  color="blue-darken-2"
  icon="mdi-message-text"
></v-icon>

<v-icon
  size="large"
  color="purple-darken-2"
  icon="mdi-dialpad"
></v-icon>

<v-icon
  size="large"
  color="teal-darken-2"
  icon="mdi-email"
></v-icon>

<v-icon
  size="large"
  color="blue-grey-darken-2"
  icon="mdi-call-split"
></v-icon>

<v-icon
  size="large"
  color="orange-darken-2"
  icon="mdi-arrow-up-bold-box-outline"
></v-icon>
</v-row>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
name: 'App',

data: () => ({
  
}),
}
```

This is how is rendering in the browser

[image: App]

I have checked all these links but futile

- [vuetify icon not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57053728/vuetify-icon-not-showing)
- [Icons not displaying in Vuetify application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59824952/icons-not-displaying-in-vuetify-application)
- https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#install-material-icons/

> **Can someone here please suggest what else is needed to render the material/font-awesome icons in the Vue app?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax for icons. For Vuetify 2, use the following:

```
<v-icon
  size="large"
  color="green-darken-2"
>mdi-domain</v-icon>
```