# Vuetify mdi icons not showing on safari

Tags: vue.js, icons, material-design, vuetify.js

I have a couple of `<v-icon>`s on my website that work fine for Chrome but don't show on Safari. I tried following the advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57053728/vuetify-icon-not-showing), but it didn't work.

I tried `npm install --save material-design-icons-iconfont`

And then in main.js I put `import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'`

I still couldn't get these icons to show up on Safari. I'm not sure what else to try here. Any ideas?

I'm running `vue@2.6.14` with `vuetify`.