# Electron build of Vue app doesn't display material icons

Tags: vue.js, electron, vuetify.js, vue-cli

Our Vue app uses `vuetify` as its component library which by default uses material design icons. The only thing [that needs to be done for the icons to work correctly](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/) is to import the css file which we do inside of the `vuetify.js` file:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib/framework";
import colors from "vuetify/lib/util/colors";
import "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: colors.orange.lighten1,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

We use [Vue CLI Plugin Electron Builder](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/) to build our app for desktop. The icons appear fine in dev mode when running `vue-cli-service electron:serve`, but if we build the app for production using `vue-cli-service electron:build` and run it on Windows or MacOS every icon is displayed as a rectangle.

[image: rectangle icons]

This is what our `package.json` looks like:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w serialport"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "serialport": "^10.5.0",
    "vue": "^2.7.14",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuetify": "^2.6.14",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@mdi/font": "^7.1.96",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^7.0.0",
    "electron": "^22.0.2",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.9.0",
    "plotly.js-dist": "2.18.2",
    "prettier": "^2.8.3",
    "sass": "^1.57.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "^3.0.0-alpha.4",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.5.8",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.9.2"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": {
      "electron-builder": "^23.1.0"
    }
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}
```

This is what our `vue.config.js` looks like:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  transpileDependencies: ["vuetify"],
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      preload: "src/preload.js",
      externals: ["serialport"],
      outputDir: "builds",
    },
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/"),
      },
    },
  },
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: '@import "~@/assets/style/_variables.scss"',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Any ideas what could be causing this? Or how we can further debug the problem?

Comment: It does mention using a CSS loader as well. I don't know if that's the case for you (I don't do much CSS stuff so I can't tell). However I did have these sort of issues at work and it almost always ended up being assets served from one path during dev but being moved to a different path when the app is bundled up and packaged. I see you're using `electron-builder` perhaps you could define some assets path? Any chance we can look at some build config?

Comment: By any chance, are you missing this line in your public/index.html file?                                       


`<link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"
    />`
I just built my electron app for production and icons show up fine. I don't have any imports like you do in my vuetify.js

Comment: @customcommander sure, thanks for trying to help. The electron builder config is inside of `vue.config.js`, I've updated the post with its contents.

Comment: vuetify version in `package.json` is 2 while the link you provided is for version 3. Can you provide an example of how you use the icon in a template?

Comment: I think you should post a minimal reproducible code, maybe in a code sandbox things. I know it's electron, but at least from that code we could try to replicate the errors first in our local machine

Comment: As I can't see in the information you provided, did you use the `iconfont` option in vuetify.js file?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to repro. Which makes your question unanswerable, considering that, ultimately, it's about CSS. Provide a repo or a codesandbox. You can remove all your business logic and only leave in a few icons and the config files, so anyone trying to help could test and find fixes/workarounds.

Comment: What I mean by my previous comment is: I made an electron app with your config, built it and I can see icons on both windows and mac. So there must be something else causing your bug, and you haven't shared it yet. Without a repro, your chances of getting a useful answer are close to null.

Answer (score 4):

The ["vuetify icon not showing" post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65012141) suggests installing `@mdi/font`, which you have done.

However, this is declared in `devDependencies`, which can be ignored when built for production, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004559/6309).

So I would first test if declaring that same `@mdi/font` packages in dependencies instead changes the "build for production" end result.

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying to help and it was a smart suggestion but unfortunately that didn't work, the same issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once using Angular + Electron. What you can do is build your app with the devTools enabled, so you can see the console errors. In my case, Jquery was being imported after bootstrap, breaking my non-dev environments.